# I have the date written in csv file as 19/10/2014.I want it in the format 19-Oct-2014

Tags: date, csv, text-formatting

I have the date in a CSV file as `19/10/2014`. I want it in the format `19-Oct-2014`.

Comment: Please post at least one line of your CSV file so that I can adjust the `awk` script below!

Answer (score 3):

The `date` command can format this for you:

```
date -d "2014-10-19" +%d-%b-%Y
```

which yields

```
19-Oct-2014
```

If you give sample lines of your file we can script it for you.

One way is using `awk`:

```
echo zzz,19/10/2014,aaa,bbb | awk -F, '{split($2,dateelem,"/"); cmd = "date -d " dateelem[3] "-" dateelem[2] "-" dateelem[1] " +%d-%b-%Y"; cmd | getline date; OFS=","; $2=date; print; close(cmd)}'
```

which gives

```
zzz,19-Oct-2014,aaa,bbb
```

Assuming here that you wish to modifiy the 2nd field.  Adjust `"split($2,dateelem,"/");"` in the `awk` script to change the field (column) number your date appears in

Comment: When processing a large file, you'll need to close the pipe after you read from it: `close cmd`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, you are right, editing...

Answer (score 2):

A solution completely in GNU awk is as follows:

```
awk '{ split($0,slt,"/");datspec=mktime(slt[3]" "slt[2]" "slt[1]" 00 00 00");print strftime("%d-%b-%Y",datspec) }' <<< "19/10/2014"
```

Taking the date as the input, we first split the data into an array (slt) to attain the date,month and year. We then use awk's mktime function to get a date spec that is then used by awk's sttftime function to get the date in the correct format.

With a csv, $0 would be the number corresponding to the comma delimited field that has the date.

Answer (score 0):

perl can do it, but it's not really for beginners. However, parsing dates is best handled by proper date handling libraries. perl has one in the box, Time::Piece

```
$ cat file
a,b,19/10/2014,d

$ perl -MTime::Piece -F, -lane '
    $F[2] = Time::Piece->strptime($F[2], "%d/%m/%Y")->strftime("%d-%b-%Y");
    print join ",", @F
' file
a,b,19-Oct-2014,d
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method

command

```
 j=`date -d "2014/10/19" +%b`;echo "19/10/2014" | awk -v j="$j" -F "/"  '{print $1"-"j"-"$3}'
```

Output

```
19-Oct-2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` approach.  Uses basic `awk` functionality, so likely to work with non-GNU implementations.

```
$ cat infile
foo,19/10/2014,bar
foo2,19/01/2015,bar2
$ awk -F, '{print $1","substr($2,0,2)"-"substr("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",substr($2,4,2)*3-2,3)"-"substr($2,7,4)","$3}' infile
foo,19-Oct-2014,bar
foo2,19-Jan-2015,bar2
$
```